# How to get registered routes in Slim Framework 4

Tags: slim-4

In Slim Framework 3 we can get all registered routes using this code

```php
$routes = $this->container->get("router")->getRoutes();
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work in slim 4. Is there any other way to get registered routes in slim 4 ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After browsing the codes, found out that you can get all routes from the `RouteCollectorProxy`. Here's an example :

```php
$routes = $app->getRouteCollector()->getRoutes();
```